# Automatic restart of SolR after Elastic Beanstalk deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a RoR application on AWS. 
My app is using SolR for the search engine, but after each deployment, the app is unable to index again. So I have to reset permissions and restart Solr manually with:

```
chmod 777 -R /solr /tmp /log
RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:stop # or I kill the processus if it doesn't work :D 
RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:start
RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:reindex
```

Now i'm trying to setup it as an eb extension to automate the deployment. 
Here is what I tried in my *.ebextensions/deploy.config*:

```
container_commands:
  1_change_permissions:
    command: chmod 700 .ebextensions/setup.sh 
  2_restart_solr:
    command: bash .ebextensions/setup.sh
```

And here is the *setup.sh* script:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod 777 -R solr/ log/ tmp/
RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:restart
```

The result is the deployment doesn't fail but, only the permissions are changed correctly, and the solr service is running but when I try to index something, it fails (the querying works fine).

I also tried to stop the server before the app is deployed by adding a *commands* block in my *.ebextensions/deploy.config* (and I changed my sh script to start the service instead of restart) :

```
commands:
  1_stop_solr:
    command: cd /var/app/current & RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:stop
```

I got this error (I don't know from where it is executed):

[2015-06-25T09:51:35.510Z] INFO  [13207] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_0_My_First_Elastic_Beanstalk_Application/Command 1_stop_solr] : Activity execution failed, because: rake aborted!
  couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~'

**EDIT 1 (following jay's comment):**
The indexation process is done when I save the objects.

Here is an example for an entity (and where it fails) :

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  # .....

  # SolR entity 
  searchable do
    text :title, :description, :tags 
    integer :user_id
  end 

  # .....

end
```

**EDIT 2: **

James' answer doesn't fix the problem but, 
I realize that manually on my EC2 instance, i can just run the 2 following lines :

```
chmod 777 -R solr/ tmp/ log/
RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:reindex"
```

I tried to use James' link to create a post-deployment script, and the chmod works well but when I add the reindex command into the file, the deployment fails with this error :

```
[2015-07-07T16:26:25.509Z] INFO  [20402] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/99_restart_delayed_job.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: rake aborted!
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources 
/var/app/current/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/app/current/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/app/current/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Also, if i try to run the command manually (after the post-deployment script chmod), it fails with 500 errors on each item to reindex. So i need to kill the solr server, start and then reindex.

It's really painful :)

Comment: How are you indexing documents? Using a script? Using post.jar file of solr? My guess is that the process which indexes does not have write permissions on the index folder of solr. That might explain why you can query (only read permission needed) but cannot index.

Comment: I updated my post with an example of indexation. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Beanstalk, but it looks like the shell that's executing your commands doesn't have the environment variables you're expecting. Assuming this blog post on [post-deployment scripts](http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/) is correct, you should be able to change your `setup.sh` script to something like this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
 . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
 cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT
 su -c "RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/rvm 2.2 do rake sunspot:solr:restart" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
```

Comment: Thank James for your answer, but it doesn't fix my problem. I added an EDIT2 part on my main post to explain what I tried

Comment: Definitely an environment issue. It looks like EB might be using RVM? Try the updated script. You might have to play with it to get the right RVM path and Ruby version.

Comment: I don't use RVM on the server. Normally the command is executed throught bundler but it doesn't work either. When I take a look deeper, I can't see any export of EB_* vars in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars file. It should be in it, right? Do I need to set those manually? Cuz when I try to print the variables, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I assume hardcoding values should be fine. As long as the the paths don't change frequently, it should be fine. Try writing a command with a hardcoded path to `bundler`. See if that gets you further.

Comment: Ok it doesn't work with the hardcoded values I tried to cd in /var/app/current and to execute : su -c with the user "ec2-user". It fails to even execute a chmod operation. And if I try to execute "bundle exec rake" with the full path of bundle i got an segmentation fault error. I didn't get any error with only rake, but it doesn't do anything (it doesn't manually).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I have written an ebextensions script that seems to work well for this case. Hopefully this will help if people are still encountering this issue.

```
commands:
    000_sudo:
        command: sudo su
    001_cd_to_app:
        command: cd /var/app/current
    002_rm_solr:
        command: rm -rf solr/
    003_start_solr:
        command: bundle exec rails sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
    004_reindex_solr:
        command: bundle exec rails sunspot:solr:reindex RAILS_ENV=production
```